# iOS swift how to change base language other than English

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I am working with Localizable file, currently I have two languages English - Development Language and other is Persian(fa-ir) 
So my base language is English now for i.e If my device has Spanish language if will execute with English language.

Now I want to change my base language English to Persian.

Comment: you can add Persian translation instead of English in base string file.

Comment: if I change this it will change only string not view like LTR-> RTL

Comment: you need to manage manually as per language direction .

Answer (score 0):

You can change your string path as below

**Objective C**

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle ] pathForResource:@"en"  ofType:@"lproj"]; // in place of "en" you can change put your locale code.
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path] ;
    NSString *string = [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:nil];
```

**Swift 3**

```
        let bundle = Bundle.main
        bundle.path(forResource: "en" as String, ofType: "lproj")// in place of "en" you can change put your locale code.
        let string = bundle.localizedString(forKey: key, value: "", table: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

It will call Before any of your code executes

Goto AppDelegate and remove `@UIApplicationMain`

Create new Swift file `main.swift`

Add following code

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

let langCultureCode: String = LanguageCode.dutch
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set([langCultureCode], forKey: appleLanguages)
defaults.synchronize()

UIApplicationMain(
CommandLine.argc,
UnsafeMutableRawPointer(CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
    .bindMemory(
        to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.self,
        capacity: Int(CommandLine.argc)),
nil,
NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)
)
```

Where

```
    let appleLanguages      =   "AppleLanguages"
```

and

```
static let dutch            =   "nl-US"
```

Comment: Thask for your reply. But this will not change my view from LTR->RTL.When I open app again it work perfectly. Do you have any solution ?

Comment: see this if helpful https://useyourloaf.com/blog/natural-text-alignment-for-rtl-languages/